# Backtracking in nonogram solver seems to be in infinite loop

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, backtracking, constraint-programming

Im trying to write o nonogram solver in Java for school homework. It works for all provided inputs except for one. My code is on github https://github.com/farkadav/Nonogram-solver

in CSPSolver I solve the nonogram. I generating all possible row/cols combinations given the constraints which are in the text files on github then I check for arc consistency and then Im trying to find solution by backtracking. I have outputs how it should look solved also. When I try to solve dino.txt my backtracking function seems to go into infinite loop solving 11th row and col and 15th col. Here is code for that method.

```
public void backtracking(){

    if(orderedVars.isEmpty()){

        String[] solString = new String[rowDim];
        for(Line line : rowSolution){

            solString[line.position] = new String();
            for(int j=0; j<colDim; j++){
                solString[line.position] +=line.value[j];
            }

        }
        String solution = new String();
        for(String sol : solString){
            solution += sol +"\n";
        }
        solutions.add(solution);
        return;
    }
    CSPVariable cspVar = orderedVars.poll();


    for(char[] var : cspVar.storage){
        if(consistent(var,cspVar)){

            if(cspVar.Row){                
                rowSolution[helpX++] = new Line(var,cspVar.position,cspVar.Row);                    
                backtracking();
                rowSolution[--helpX] = null;
            } else{
                colSolution[helpY++] = new Line(var,cspVar.position,cspVar.Row);                    
                backtracking();
                colSolution[--helpY] = null;
            }
        }
    }
    orderedVars.add(cspVar);

}
```

and I dont know what is causing it exactly, any help will be appreciated. If anything is unclear here is link to the assignment http://cw.fel.cvut.cz/wiki/courses/a4b33zui/task2-malovane-krizovky-en

Answer (score 0):

Calling backtracking() inbetween manipulating helpX and helpY looks questionable to me. If it's not necessary from the definition of the algorithm try reordering it that way, such helpX and helpY are modified before backtracking() is called.

Comment: Im afraid it is necessary from the definition of the algorithm. However, I could be wrong Im not guru in csp. Anyway... I tried it anyway and it crashes the whole program. Thank you for your suggestion :)